# Android: ENOENT error getting photo from a third-party camera app

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm using the [stock Android Java code](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#java) to take a photo from my app. It works great with the default camera. When I use a third-party camera app, I get an error popup (not from my app) and the image that the app receives is blank: `/myapp_app_images/JPEG_20191016....jpg: open failed: ENOENT (no such file or directory)`. The `myapp_app_images` path is set in file_paths.xml as the `external-path`:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="myapp_app_images" path="Android/data/com.myapp/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

With the third-party camera app, my app never reaches my Activity's `onActivityResult`. It does with the native camera.

Is this a flaw with the third-party app, and if yes, is there a workaround from my side?  One idea I have is that perhaps the photo from the third-party camera is being saved to a location it can't access, or the path is being reported incorrectly or missing the full path. But I'm not sure how to check or solve either of these problems, or if there is a different cause.

My intent and handler, with some error handling shortened for clarity:

```
private void goToCamera() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
           ...
        }

        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.myapp.fileprovider", photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_PHOTO_CAPTURE);
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a bug in the third-party app, which isn't implementing handling the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent correctly.

For example, it may be expecting a file:// URI only, instead of the now-required content:// URI.  Or some other issue.

Unfortunately, the only way to fix this is likely for the application developer of the third-party app to do so.